# TensorFlow 2.13.0 Protobuf FATAL ERROR on Inference C++ test

Tags: tensorflow, c++17, protocol-buffers, tensorflow2.0, protobuf-c

I just compiled TensorFlow 2.13.0, on Slackware with kernel 4.19.288 with nvidia Driver Version: 535.54.03 and CUDA Version: 12.2, C++ APIs. When I try to start compiled inference test it gives me this error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:642] File already exists in database: tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/xla_framework.proto
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1986] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
Aborted
```

The same program on Ubuntu 22.04 works fine.